# www-data has access to folders in my home directory

Tags: permissions

I've never noticed this before and I have no idea how this has happened but www-data has privilages to files in my home directory, here is what I have.

```
drwx------  2 root www-data 4096 Jul 20 22:06 Mail
drwx------ 10 root www-data 4096 Aug 10 15:21 Maildir
drwxr-xr-x  2 root www-data 4096 Sep 15 23:57 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data    0 Jul 18 22:21 oot
drwxrwxrwx  2 root www-data 4096 Oct  4 16:05 s
```

What should I do and should I be worried?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, www-data is the group used by web servers you might have installed (probably apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www-data is used by apache for example. 
you can easily remove the access for www-data and give back to root or any other user by using this command:

```
sudo chown -R root:root
```

Comment: Files in one's home directory should be owned by the user, not root. Also take care with the use of -R , you can do a bit of damage with -R. `sudo chown -R user:user /home/user`